# How can I use volume normalization with Grooveshark?

Tags: grooveshark

One major downside of Grooveshark is that the songs vary wildly in volume.  Constantly adjusting is annoying and occasionally painful (if it goes from a quiet song to a loud one).  Is there any way to do volume normalization?

Comment: For now I'm using [this very useful AutoHotkey script](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/scripts/VolumeOSD.htm) with a step of 1% to make things a bit simpler, but normalization would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything that works with **Grooveshark** specifically, but I did find these tips at **How To Geek** useful.

- [3 Ways to normalize sound volume on your PC](http://www.howtogeek.com/115656/3-ways-to-normalize-sound-volume-on-your-pc/)

Hope that helps you.

Also, this articles gives a bit more information on the whole normalisation process, its merits, etc.

- [How To Normalize Audio – Why Do It? Everything You Need To Know](http://www.learndigitalaudio.com/blog/normalize-audio)